# Which Youtube API scope should I use in order to access my own video's tags in Youtube API v3

Tags: python, youtube, youtube-api, google-api-python-client

I try to retrieve videos' tags using Python API client for Youtube API v3, and I receive snippet without .tags in it. API scope seems to be the reason for me.

Comment: Can you post some code, so we can see what you are trying to do? Are you authenticating before making the request?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need client library for Python. I was using "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube"

Check [YouTube API Sample](https://code.google.com/p/youtube-api-samples/source/browse/samples/python/update_video.py) for this.